# Spark: Task not Serializable for UDF on DataFrame

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` when I try to execute the following on Spark 1.4.1:

```
import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

object ConversionUtils {
  val iso8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")

  def tsUTC(s: String): Timestamp = new Timestamp(iso8601.parse(s).getTime)

  val castTS = udf[Timestamp, String](tsUTC _)
}

val df = frame.withColumn("ts", ConversionUtils.castTS(frame("ts_str")))
df.first
```

Here, `frame` is a `DataFrame` that lives within a `HiveContext`. That data frame does not have any issues.

I have similar UDFs for integers and they work without any problem. However, the one with timestamps seems to cause problems. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), `java.sql.TimeStamp` implements `Serializable`, so that's not the problem. The same is true for `SimpleDateFormat` as can be seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

This causes me to believe it's the UDF that's causing problems. However, I'm not sure what and how to fix it.

The relevant section of the trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ...
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: ..., value: ...$ConversionUtils$@63ed11dd)
        - field (class: ...$ConversionUtils$$anonfun$3, name: $outer, type: class ...$ConversionUtils$)
        - object (class ...$ConversionUtils$$anonfun$3, <function1>)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf$$anonfun$2, name: func$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf, scalaUDF(ts_str#2683))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, scalaUDF(ts_str#2683) AS ts#7146)
        - element of array (index: 35)
        - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 36)
        - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
        - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer,
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try:

```
object ConversionUtils extends Serializable {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @CharlieRosenfeld An object needs to be serialized to be sent to a processing node. So, a function that needs to be run on a node needs to be defined on a serializable object

Comment: worked like a charm.. Thanks @DavidGriffin Although i want to know why this is happening. can you comment some links where this problem is explained clearly?

Comment: @ChaitanyaVemulakonda there is an in-depth article about it https://medium.com/swlh/spark-serialization-errors-e0eebcf0f6e6 (methods basically need to have parent objects Serializable so that they can be sent to executors)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and even extending Serialization did not work.
Before any action try to persist the data. This worked for me.

```
DF.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```