# UDF returns "sc not serializable"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I have a dataset from a Cassandra database, created using the below code snippet, then I'm trying to create a UDF over one of the columns. However, when doing so I get the error `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf`.

```
sc.stop()
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "database.url").
  set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "UNAME").
  set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "PASSWORD");
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "test", conf);
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
import sqlContext.implicits._
val dfSurvey = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
    options(Map("keyspace" -> "KEYSPACE_NAME", "table" -> "TABLE_NAME")).
    load()
```

I have simplified the UDF to be just the length of the string in a given column. For testing purposes, here are 2 UDFs:

```
def test(s:String) : Int = s.length
val udf1 = udf((s:String) => test(s))
val udf2 = udf((s:String) => s.length)
val df1 = dfSurvey.withColumn("respText",responseFromJsonTest($"json"))
val df2 = dfSurvey.withColumn("respText",responseFromJsonTest2($"json"))
```

Calling `df2.show(1)` works fine, but calling `df1.show(1)` gives the error. I don't get how 1 path requires serialization of sc and the other doesn't. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is a *method* of the encompassing class (which isn't presented in the post, but it undoubtedly exists). As a method of a class used in a UDF, Spark must *serialize* the instance of that class in order to use it remotely on the executors (UDFs are applied to the data which is distributed across executor JVMs). That same instance also contains a member named `sc` (of type `SparkContext`) which is not serializable (as the error message states), so the serialization fails.

The working example (`df2.show(1)`) works because it does not use a *method*, rather an *anonymous function* which does not reference the encapsulating class and therefore can be serialized (does not have to serialize the non-serializable `SparkContext`).

To workaround that issue while still using a named method (e.g. `test`), you can place that method:

1. In an *object*, so that it need not be serialized
2. In a *serializable class* (a class that extents `Serializable` and has no members that aren't serializable themselves)
3. You can define a named function that is not a method of any class:

   ```
   val test: String => Int = s => s.length
   ```

Comment: About 2 hours after I posted this, I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794688/spark-task-not-serializable-for-udf-on-dataframe?rq=1) which says just what you did. Putting the "offending" code into an object worked perfectly. Thanks.