# Spark scala UDF is getting Task not serializable error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create UDF using the below scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
object dataframes extends App {
    def ageCheck(age: Int):String = {if(age>18) "Y" else "N"}
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testing").master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    val withOutHeaderDF = spark.read.format("csv")
        .option("inferSchema", true)
        .option("path","D:/1. Technologies/Big Data/sharedPath/dataset1.csv")
        .load()
    val withHeaderDF: Dataset[Row] = withOutHeaderDF.toDF("name","age","city")
    import spark.implicits._
    val definedAgeCheck = udf(ageCheck(_:Int):String)
    val finalResult = withHeaderDF.withColumn("Adult",definedAgeCheck(col("age")))
    finalResult.show
    spark.stop()
}
```

But I obtain a `Task not serializable` error.

Comment: Try defining your `ageCheck` using val, since `def ageCheck(x: Int): ...` is a method, not a function. Or let the compiler do it for you, like this: `val definedAgeCheck = udf(ageCheck _)`

Comment: Does this or other posts that google returns for "UDF not serializable" answer your question? [Spark: Task not Serializable for UDF on DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794688/spark-task-not-serializable-for-udf-on-dataframe)

Comment: @mazaneicha tried that.. but that doesn't helped

Comment: @AminMal tried but getting same error

Comment: Add a stacktrace?